# Is injection from manifold to tangent manifold well defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I would like to know if the injection map $i : M\to TM$, given by $i(x)\mapsto (x,0)$, is a well-defined and canonical application (not dependent on any particular coordinate chart).

Comment: Yes, this is the [zero section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle#Sections_and_locally_free_sheaves), which exists in every vector bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "yes."  You should prove it yourself as an exercise.

(Hint: the transition functions are smooth maps $\theta_{UV}:U\cap V\to Gl(n;\mathbb{R})$.  In particular, for all $x\in U\cap V$, $\theta_{UV}(x)$ is a linear map.  What does this say about how $i$ transforms between coordinate systems?)